# BibTeX problem with math symbols

Tags: math-mode, bibtex, symbols

I'm using BibTex for my bibliography, for citing I'm using google scholar.  I'm mainly having problems with math symbols: for example, one of the references is:

```
@incollection{deitmar2005schemes,  
  title={Schemes over$\backslash$  mathbb $\{$F$\}$ \_1},  
  author={Deitmar, Anton},  
  booktitle={Number fields and function fields—two parallel worlds},  
  pages={87--100},  
  year={2005},  
  publisher={Springer}    
}
```

But it comes out wrong, the nice `$\mathbb{F}_1$` math symbol is missing and what I see is only `\mathbb {F}_1`. Is the cite BibTeX of google scholar wrong?

```
Another problem: google scholar gives me this:  
@article{kurokawa2005zeta,  
  title={Zeta functions over $$\backslash$ mathbf $\{$F$\}$ \_1$},  
  author={Kurokawa, Nobushige and others},  
  journal={Proceedings of the Japan Academy, Series A, Mathematical   Sciences},  
  volume={81},  
  number={10},  
  pages={180--184},  
  year={2005},  
  publisher={The Japan Academy}  
}
```

But the output is very messy: there is no math symbol for `$\mathbb{F}_1$` and the "Proceedings of the Japan Academy, Series A, Mathematical   Sciences" come out without spaces and actually runs out of the page.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Apart from the wrong formating (see egreg's answer) You need `amssymb` package for `\mathbb`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Those references are badly formatted:

```
title={Schemes over {$\mathbb{F}_1$}},
```

and

```
title={Zeta functions over {$\mathbf{F}_1$}},
```

should be the right ways. Although I'd use `\mathbf` for both; check the original papers to see the right formatting.

Also the `—` in the `booktitle` field should be `---`:

In the example I use `filecontents*` so that it is self-contained. Fix your `.bib` file and use it.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{deitmar2005schemes,  
  title={Schemes over {$\mathbb{F}_1$}},  
  author={Deitmar, Anton},  
  booktitle={Number fields and function fields---two parallel worlds},  
  editor={Gerard van der Geer and Ben Moonen and Ren{\'e} Schoof},
  pages={87--100},  
  year={2005},  
  publisher={Birkh{\"a}user Boston}
}  
@article{kurokawa2005zeta,  
  title={Zeta functions over {$\mathbf{F}_1$}},  
  author={Kurokawa, Nobushige and others},  
  journal={Proceedings of the Japan Academy, Series A, Mathematical Sciences},  
  volume={81},  
  number={10},  
  pages={180--184},  
  year={2005},  
  publisher={The Japan Academy}  
}  
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

I cite \cite{deitmar2005schemes} and \cite{kurokawa2005zeta}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A check in MathSciNet reveals that the second reference is by a single author and also has `\mathbb`, so it should be

```
@article {kurokawa2005zeta,
  author = {Kurokawa, Nobushige},
  title = {Zeta functions over {$\mathbb{F}_1$}},
  journal = {Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci.},
  fulljournal = {Japan Academy. Proceedings. Series A. Mathematical Sciences},
  volume = {81},
  year = {2005},
  number = {10},
  pages = {180--184},
}
```

Change `journal` into `shortjournal` and `fulljournal` into `journal` if you want to have the full journal name spelled out.

Comment: Yes, \mathbf looks much better!

Comment: the deitmar reference definitely uses blackboard bold; just checked in mathscinet.  the other reference isn't covered there.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. The second reference is with a single author, MR2196724

Comment: @Tyche I've added some fixes for the second reference.

Comment: @egreg -- aha!  thanks!  (when i couldn't find the paper by title, i looked for the journal, and didn't find that either.  your search technique is sure better than mine!)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of correcting the "publisher" field information and supplying the missing "editor" field in one of the entries.

Comment: @Mico Thanks; however I trust MathSciNet for the capitalization of the title (no capitalization in this case).

Comment: I took the capitalization from the book itself; see, e.g., http://www.amazon.com/Number-Fields-Function-Parallel-Mathematics/dp/0817643974/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1436166333&sr=8-3-fkmr0&keywords=Number+fields+and+function+fields+deitmar#reader_0817643974