# How to reference an article which consists superscripts in its title?

Tags: biblatex

I have a problem in referencing an article. The title has some superscript. It is giving error when I

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Use math mode in your bib-file as you would use in your tex-file.

Comment: How to do it? I am new to this environment.

Comment: The proper code for this would be `$M^{2}$`.  But really, you should read some basic documentation about LaTeX math.

Comment: Can you tell us what your `.bib` entry looks like. It would also help if we knew which bibliography style you use (and which bibliography/citation package). Some styles apply additional formatting to titles that could be relevant here. Please add a short example document to your question that reproduces the issue: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253852/15925 help?

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @barbarabeeton $M^{2}$ did work for me. Thanks

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so we can mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 4):

Properly coded in-line math can be used in a `.bib` file.

In the present case the math should be entered as

```
title = {The {$M^{2}$} algorithm},
```

Any good introduction to (La)TeX will explain math coding. The braces are meant to disable automatic lowercasing done by some styles, see [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/).